# Concatenation of a Complicated String Causing Issues

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0

I have assigned a piece of code to a string in a proper format. Checked that it works fine. Now I wish to get a copy of this code concatenated to the old code on a button click.Also there are variables within the string which take up values from textboxes. But somehow these variables(arrays) are not able to store the last values. I want to generate the code while placing all the variables at proper places.

```
  public string oldCode;
    public int counter=0;
    string[] AffUrl = new string[100];
    string[] ImgUrl = new string[100];
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        AffUrl[counter] =textBox1.Text;
        ImgUrl[counter] = textBox2.Text;


        string code = @"<div style=""float:left;padding-right:30px;padding-bottom:30px;"">
<div>
  <img src=""" + ImgUrl[counter] + @""" height=""200px"" width=""200px"" />
</div>
<div>
  <button onclick=""myFunction()"">Try it</button>
  <script type=""text/javascript"">
    function myFunction" + counter + @"() {
      var btn = document.createElement(""BUTTON"");
      window.open(""" + AffUrl[counter] + @""", ""_self"")
    }
  </script>
</div>
  </div>";
       oldCode = code;
       oldCode = string.Concat(code,oldCode);
       counter++;

       richTextBox1.Text =oldCode; 
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got it!
You can place a condition over "oldCode=code;

```
    public string oldCode;
    public int counter = 0;
    string[] AffUrl = new string[100];
    string[] ImgUrl = new string[100];
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        AffUrl[counter] = textBox1.Text;
        ImgUrl[counter] = textBox2.Text;

        string code = @"<div style=""float:left;padding-right:30px;padding-bottom:30px;"">
<div>
  <img src=""" + ImgUrl[counter] + @""" height=""200px"" width=""200px"" />
</div>
<div>
  <button onclick=""myFunction()"">Try it</button>
  <script type=""text/javascript"">
    function myFunction" + counter + @"() {
      var btn = document.createElement(""BUTTON"");
      window.open(""" + AffUrl[counter] + @""", ""_self"")
    }
  </script>
</div>
 </div>";
        if (counter == 0)
        {
            oldCode = code;
        }
        oldCode = string.Concat(code, oldCode);
        counter++;

        richTextBox1.Text = oldCode;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

As written, you're always concatenating the new value to itself.  Remove the `oldCode = code` assignment.

Comment: What is it that doesn't work? Are you saying that the concatenation doesn't give the correct result, or that the values in the arrays are incorrect?

Comment: Brother, I solved the problem, you can refer to the code below. "oldCode=code;" used to reset "oldCode" on each button click. So I have put a condition over it.

Comment: Glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
  </div>";
   oldCode = code; <= here you reset the cache - are you sure that's intended?
   oldCode = string.Concat(code,oldCode);
```